# Java putting common methods inside superclass

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism

I have two classes that both take the same type of object as an argument, but then call a different method on that object to obtain another object (the obtained object's type is also different in both classes) that is used extensively throughout the classes in different methods. Now, some of these methods are identical between the two classes, so I thought that it would be wise to put them in a subclass. However, since the methods are dependent on the object that was obtained by calling a different method on the object given as an argument to the constructors, i can't just copy the constructors from subclasses to the superclass. I'm uncertain how can the superclass obtain the required object. It seems that my potential superclass `Server` would be dependent on its subclasses, which even sounds wrong.

Here's an illustrative code of the problem:

```
class ServerOne() {

    Connector connector; 

    public ServerOne(Conf conf) {
        Conf.ServerOneConf config = conf.getServerOneConf();
        connector = config.getConnector(); // 
    }

    // a lot of methods that use connector
}

class ServerTwo() {

    Connector connector;

    public ServerTwo(Conf conf) {
        Conf.ServerTwoConf config = conf.getServerTwoConf(); // notice that it uses a different method for obtaining the configuration. Also, the obtained object is of a different type than the configuration object that was obtained in the ServerOne constructor. 

        connector = config.getConnector();
    }

    // a lot of methods that use connector
}

class Server() {
    // would like to implement some common methods that use connector.
    // need to get an instance of the Connector to this class. 
}
```

Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be reasons to subclass your Server class, but how to get the connector probably isn't a reason for subclassing. Make a strategy to handle getting a Connector:

```
interface ConnectorStrategy {
    Connector retrieveConnector(Conf conf);
}
```

with implementations like

```
class ServerOneConnectorStrategy implements ConnectorStrategy {
    public Connector retrieveConnector(Conf conf) {
        return conf.getServerOneConf().getConnector();
    }
}
```

and pass this in to the Server object when you create it.

Or if you need the hierarchy, use the [template method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern):

```
abstract class Server {
    abstract Connector retrieveConnector(Conf conf);
    void initializeConnector(Conf conf) {
        ...
        connector = retrieveConnector(conf);
    }
    ...
}

class ServerOne extends Server {
    public Connector retrieveConnector(Conf conf) {
         return conf.getServerOneConf().getConnector();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is this approach better than just creating private methods inside the subclasses for returning connector? Also, is the thing i'm trying to accomplish good design? I mean, the existence of the Server class alone would not make any sense as it is heavily dependent on the connector created in the subclasses. Maybe a helper class would make more sense ? Thank you.

Comment: @Sten: you can still do something like this making an abstract method on the superclass and have the subclasses implement it.

Comment: You mean to put the retrieveConnector method in your example in the superclass as an abstract method?

Comment: Does this construction seem reasonable? Having to implement an abstract method in order to initialize an abstract class seems a bit strange imo :d

Comment: @Sten: you're giving the superclass a way to get its configuration that defers to the subclass for subclass-specific implementation. that's what abstract methods are for.

Comment: where are all "implements" and "extends"...?

Answer (score 1):

How about making Server as an abstract class and extends ServerOne and ServerTwo from it.

Like this:

```
public abstract class Server() {
   Connector connector;
   public Server() {
      Configuration config = conf.getServerTwoConf();
      connector = config.getConnector();
   }
...
}  

class ServerOne() extends Server{
...
}

class ServerTwo() extends Server{
...
}
```

Comment: This would be ideal, but as i tried to convey, both of the subclasses use different methods for obtaining the Configuration. Also, I forgot to mention that the Configuration object obtained does not have the same type in both classes. I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Ok, then you just have to put all your common methods in the super class and make a unique constructor for all the extended classes

Comment: The problem is that before calling the parent's constructor with a given argument, some logic has to be done in the subclasses first to obtain the argument passed to the parent's, as can be seen from the example. However, calling the parent's constructor would have to be the first thing done in the child's constructor. Executing the logic (which in reality is more extensive ofcourse) inside the parantheses of the super() keyword would be undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect case for extending a superclass.  The object you are populating in both constructors is of the same type - not the same data.  When you create a ServerOne, it will populate the object held in the superclass the way you currently do.  Then, the common methods in the superclass can now operate on this object that is populated.

Answer (score 0):

Put your shared methods in the super class

```
class Server() {

      Connector connector; 

      public Server(Conf conf) {
          Configuration config = conf.getServerConf();
          connector = config.getConnector(); // 
      }

      // your methods
}
```

and then just use the `super()` call in the constructor of your subclasses. They can easily inherit the methods of your super class without having to write them again.

```
class ServerOne() extends Server {

    public ServerOne(Conf conf) {
        super(conf);
    }
}
```

Comment: The configuration can't be uniformly obtained from the superclass, because both of the subclasses use a different method for obtaining it.

Comment: use `super(conf.getServerOneConf())` or something like that